# XPath for attribute based on predecessor's attribute value?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

So I have something like this

```
<img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"> <a href="convobot-main/">convobot-main/</a>
```

and I want to select the `a href` only when the `img` tag has the attribute `alt = "[Dir]"`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Check if the img tag has attribute alt: https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-check-if-an-element-has-attribute-using-jquery-and-javascript . Then select the a href if the condition is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//img[@alt='[DIR]']/following-sibling::a[1]/@href
```

will select `href` attributes of all first `a` siblings of all `img` elements with an `alt` attribute value of `'[DIR]'`.

Comment: Ok thanks the following-sibling was really helpful! I had it to remove the [1] and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm curious about your having to remove the `[1]`.  That would select *all* following `a` siblings, not just the first.  Is that what you need?